# Why does this program hang? Google App Engine and Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, math, webapp2, palindrome

This program is supposed to compute a numeric palindrome, when data is input via a web form. It did run properly on localhost environment using just python and the web.py framework. But since then, I ported it to the google app engine, using webapp2 framework, so that I can launch this on a public server. When I refactored code for this new framework, something got off in the lines of code dealing with the computation. Hoping someone can help solve this.

Below is the class that handles getting the input from browser. I've tested and it seems to get that input fine. Then it sends it to `compute_palintip`, which is supposed to solve the palindrome (final amount). It is hanging here.

```
class result(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        form = self.request.get_all('entries', default_value = None)
        if form[0]:
            if form[1]:
                orig_dollar_amount = cgi.escape(form[0])
                tip_percent = cgi.escape(form[1])
                final_amount = compute_palintip(float(orig_dollar_amount),
                                                float(tip_percent))
                actual_tip_percent = final_amount - orig_dollar_amount
                actual_tip_percent = actual_tip_percent*100/orig_dollar_amount
```

This is the `compute_palintip` code and its helper function:

```
def compute_palintip(orig_dollar_amount, tip_percent):

    orig_amount_cents = orig_dollar_amount*100
    final_amount = orig_amount_cents*(1.0 + tip_percent/100.0)
    while(is_palindrome(final_amount) == False): 
        final_amount += 1
    final_amount = final_amount/100
    final_amount = round(final_amount, 2)
    return final_amount

def is_palindrome(num):

    num_str = str(num)
    num_str_len = len(num_str)
    for i in range(num_str_len):
        if num_str[i] != num_str[num_str_len-i-1]:
            return False
    return True
```

A few notes:

- I had to convert the input into floats in order to send them to the `compute_palintip` function.
- Couldn't convert to ints because they do not allow decimal places (cents are needed for these inputs related to restaurant dollar amounts).
- I also have to use the float type I'm pretty sure, because neither Strings nor Ints will be able to operate with the formulas which are also floats. Python wants them all the same.
- However, it seems that the math is now wonky since the floats and ints got mixed up, and it is not terminating.

The math was written by a colleague, whereas I was writing the UI type stuff, which is why I'm not really able to debug it at this point, so I am hoping someone else can spot a solution I'm not seeing. Thanks.

Comment: Also, here's the webform that the program is pulling the input data from, in case it helps: `<form action="/result" method="POST">
    Original dollar amount of meal: <input type="text" name="entries" />
    <br/>
    Target tip percentage: <input type="text" name="entries" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />
</form>`

Comment: Applications can't hang in appengine. Requests will be terminated after 60 seconds with a DeadlineExceededError.  Please check your logs and see what the error is, and the stacktrace. Then you might get an answer that is helpful.

Comment: Does it work locally with the [AppEngine devserver](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver)? It may be easier to debug on your local machine than on AppEngine itself.

Comment: Please check you app logs in the console.  My guess is that you're getting an 'Expected float, got string' error, especially at `actual_tip_percent = actual_tip_percent*100/orig_dollar_amount`

Comment: @Tim Hoffman I tried that repeatedly, but it literally is not throwing any error or exception, as it is in an infinite loop, it is just hanging indefinitely until I terminate the app engine. The normal log is of no use.

Comment: @MishaBrukman This is very helpful, thanks so much. I got it running in appengine devserver, which let me step through each line. I have now isolated the problem as the while loop in compute_palintip, which in turn calls the for loop in is_palindrome and never stops.

Comment: You should always say if your running on the dev server or in the live environment.

Comment: When working with dollar amounts I would either use int's or Decimal with a defined precision rather than floats.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can set some logging to see the flow of the program.  When dealing in floats, be consistent in your arithmetic, and use decimals after each number:
`orig_dollar_amount*100.0`
`final_amount/100.0`
`final_amount += 1.0`
`actual_tip_percent*100.0/orig_dollar_amount`

Also, you failed to cast `orig_dollar_amount` to a float

Comment: Thx. I believe I fixed the casting of the orig_dollar_amount into a float in my latest version, but the bug still remains in the compute_palintip function, as it tries to increase final_amount until it's a palindrome, but gets stuck in an infinite loop..

Answer (score 0):

What are the numbers you've input?  There are cases where `is_palindrome` never returns True. e.g. `1234567890`.  It will go through the entire string, and return `False` for every test.

Comment: This is worth noting, but I solved this by converting the float to an int and then to a string, within the is_palindrome function. The incrementing is done on the decimal level, then the resulting number is tested on the int level so it always finds the next palindrome.

Comment: Converting a float to an int gets rid of the cents.  Are you sure that's the behavior you want?  Also, you never handled the decimal point in the string, which will never match the palindrome test. So, while a string of the floated number, do a `.replace('.', '')` to get rid of the decimal, but leave the cents.  I still say that some values will hang, as the `is_palindrome` test never returns True.

Comment: As mentioned, it's all fully ironed out, and unit tests are passing. The int conversion is done after multiplying by 100, so the cents are preserved in any case, and then it is converted back into decimal form and rounded. So that takes care of the decimal point, as it is removed for palindrome checking, and re-added for display purposes. `is_palindrome` looks like this now: `def is_palindrome(num):
    num_str = str(int(num))
    num_str_len = len(num_str)
    for i in range(num_str_len):
        if num_str[i] != num_str[num_str_len-i-1]:
            return False
    return True`

Comment: Yes, because a float always has a decimal place.  123.45 * 100.0 = 12345.0.  That is why casting to an int solved that.  Or, you could have removed the decimal point in the string.  But, I still think your logic is incorrect.  Did you indent the `return True`?  I could not tell from your inline code sample.  A number with an even number of digits, like 123456, will never return True in your previous code.  A number with an odd number of digits will always return True eventually, as the center digit will always match itself.

Comment: `return True` is not indented further than the `for`, so it is outside of the `if` statement. It returns True when `num_str[i] = num_str[num_str_len-i-1]`. The parity of the number of digits is inconsequential on whether `is_palindrome` returns True or False, as it is neutral to the number of digits; it simply checks if the condition is met. Keep in mind that `orig_amount_cents` has changed the decimal place, so we're dealing in hundreds of pennies, not single dollars. See for yourself at http://third-fire-595.appspot.com/ it checks out in all cases I am aware of, having thoroughly tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issues, thanks for the help everyone. The decimal places had to be exact, and I had to be sure in each place of choosing whether to use ints / floats / strings, etc. in order to get the proper outcome. Line by line debugging, testing various examples, and correcting the flaws one by one was the only way to go.

The prototype app of this code is up and running at http://third-fire-595.appspot.com/ , by the way, for anyone interested in playing with it. please feel free to test out some combinations and let me know any feedback.